# syntaxerror unexpected token } nodejs

Tags: javascript, web

i cannot find my problem!

```
/var/www/html/bot# nodejs driver
```

```
/var/www/html/bot/driver.js:2239
   });
   ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

if i go on line 2239 there is nothing! i had this problem before with line 1631 and i tried to fix and now its line 2239

please help me out!

edit:

last lines

```
function time() {
  return parseInt(new Date().getTime()/1000)
}

function generate(count) {
    return crypto.randomBytes(count).toString('hex');
}

function array_limit(wartosc){
  if(chat_history.length==25){
    chat_history.shift();
    chat_history.shift();
  }
  chat_history.push(wartosc);
}

function jp_limit(wartosc){
  if(jpWinners.length==10){
    jpWinners.shift();
  }
  jpWinners.push(wartosc);
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

i cannot see the problem in my last lines...

Comment: Well, what is around line 2239? Where is the closest curly brace?

Comment: i cannot format it :/

Comment: Please add your code as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51975240/edit) to your question instead of a comment, there you can also format it.

Comment: What did you do to fix line 1631?

Comment: look before line 2239, not just at line 2239 - try using a linter (jshint/jslint)

Comment: i deleted curly brace and else

Comment: i dont understand where there is one brace too much... these are the last lines with function getrandomint

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right in front of you:

```
/var/www/html/bot/driver.js:2239
});
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

Do you see the symbol just below the closing curly brace on the second line?

This is a visual indicator of where your error occurs.

Also, on line 3 you see the error message itself - "unexpected token" - and then the unexpected token itself - "}".

What you've done most likely is that you added an additional closing curly brace OR you didn't add the opening curly brace at first place.

A good approach usually is to type both curly braces at the very beginning when defining a new object and then going one space to the left, press Enter and voila - you have an empty object with a proper number of curly braces. Now, you just have to fill it in with the properties you need.

Comment: yes i know that, and i tried to delete that brace, but its not working... if i delete the error occurs somewhere else

Comment: exactly, you either have an extra closing/opening curly brace or a missing opening/closing one. 
debugging this really sucks, I know. you more or less have to go thru all objects defined and track them one by one. that's why I added the last comment in my answer, it's just a good practice.

Comment: cannot i find out which it is? with any program/site? like its telling me where a brace should be to end that one?

Comment: or how can i post the full code? so you can see which line :/

Comment: what you can do I to install an IDE like VS Code or Atom or something like that. In all of these tools for writing code you usually have the ability to set your pointer on one curly brace (or bracket or parenthesis) and it will show you where the other one is. Try it out!

Comment: okay thank you alot! ill try that out... sitting here like 4-5 hours now.. ill try tomorrow... if i cannot get this done is it possible that someone looking over it? :-)

Comment: usually, people are pasting almost all of their code here. however, that's not always the best. if you are new to programming it's super important to get used to debugging and tracing back stupid errors. that's when you actually learn. 
but installing VS Code, for example, will help you out immediately.
just have in mind that if an opening or closing curly brace is missing you won't be able to see where exactly to add it but will give you at least the general direction or an area where to look at. it's a detective work, in my opinion.